# Copy Vertex Color from specific face (one object) to selected faces (another object)

Tags: vertices, vertex-colors

I found only one way to transfer vertex colors from one object to another object: via Ctrl+L transfer Mesh Data, but this transfers all vertex colors and with different topology actually randomly (all faces get colored randomly). When entering Edit Mode having both Object selected, I cannot transfer Face Data via Ctrl+C (unless the faces are from the same object). Is there no way to copy a face attribute from one object to another object's face?